# How to vectorise these two nested for-loops?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.zeros((42, 123, 2021))

assert another_array.shape == (42, 123)

for i in range(42):
    for j in range(123):
        my_array[i, j, another_array[i, j]] = 1
```

where it is assumed that the values of another_array stay inside the correct range (i.e. the values of another_array are integers between 0 and 2020).

I would like to get rid of the two for-loops. Is there a way to vectorise something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my_array = np.zeros((42, 123, 2021))
# assert another_array.shape == (42, 123)
my_array[ np.arange(42)[:,None], np.arange(123), another_array] = 1
```

The idea is to replace the `i,j` with a pair of ranges that broadcast to (42,123) to match the 3rd axis index array.

Comment: This is a lot faster than my solution using .flatten(). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.zeros((42, 123, 2021))
my_array = my_array.reshape(-1, 2021)

assert another_array.shape == (42, 123)
another_array = another_array.flatten()

my_array[range(my_array.shape[0]), another_array] = 1
my_array = my_array.reshape(42, 123, 2021)
```

Comment: The for loop is ~1.14x faster on average on my machine.

Comment: A slightly faster (~1.12x) solution than the for loop I could find `row, col = np.indices(another_array.shape);
my_array[row.ravel(), col.ravel(), another_array.ravel()] = 1`. Not worth an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny are you testing with big enough arrays? It is known that if you work with just a few values numpy tends to be slower than pure python.

Comment: @user2640045 - I benchmarked with OPs arrays and 25x the size. I thought it would be particularly interesting for OP's use case.

Comment: An other approach could be to make it a function and @numba.jit it.

Comment: I forgot to adjust the first `for` loop to `range(1000)` for a (1000, 123, 2021)-array. There is an advantage of ~1.3x for this vectorized solution with larger arrays. `numba` `njit` speeds up the `for` loops by 1.22x.